# JQuery mobile 1.3.2 event - after page show

Tags: jquery-mobile

I often need to do do manipulation after the dom is ready.

I use the event beforepageshow, but it is actually called before the dom is fully rendered (for example header height is 0).

therefore I do a settimeout(..., 500) which is ok but it might fail on slow devices and the result is a bit jumpy.

what I really need is a afterpageshow event that is triggered after the page is fully displayed - which would be the REAL equivalent to Jquery document ready event.

I have the following possibilities:

1. use beforepageshow + settimeout
2. hack JQM and add a afterpageshow event - can someone explain how?
3. Or that i'm missing something basic regarding the JQM events.

Any info about 1,2, or 3?

Comment: `pageshow` or even `pagechange` as it fires after showing page.

Comment: Do you which event fires on 'back' (i.e. history(-1)) ?

Comment: All events fire except for `pagebeforecreate`, `pagecreate` and `pageinit` as previous page is already created and initialized.